# Append options to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT without modification on files

Tags: boot, grub2, configuration, packaging

I want to add an option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` without modifying any files on the system. The reason is that I want to apply it by installing a driver package, but currently I haven't found any way to do that without touching `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/grub/10_linux`. I tried to add it with the script below which should be executed before `10_linux` but it has no effect:

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/09_linux_vmalloc 
    #!/bin/sh
    set -e

    export GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT vmalloc=256MB"
```

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly you are trying to do, or why, but you can edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly without editing /etc files, or you can run `grub-mkconfig` and then modify the output.

Comment: @bain I'd suggest posting that (or something like it) as an answer.

Comment: Well, that'S not what I want to do. I just want to provide a file (placed somewhere) to make update-grub append my needed option _without_ changing any (upstream) files. I already done that years before using a script, but it broke (somehow) others /etc/default/grub . Just want to avoid that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newer grub packages now provide to add files with own modifications at /etc/default/grub.d/ .
In my case I was able to modify grub with my packaging by:

```
thopiekar@t91:~$ cat /etc/default/grub.d/emgd.cfg 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT vmalloc=256MB selinux=0 vga=current"
```

Thank you all anyway :)

Comment: How new? Which Ubuntu version started supporting this?

Comment: Don't know. Just found it after installing linux-crashdump to debug a kernel module. kexec is using to to pass parameters to grub.

Comment: Interesting. It's been supported since 12.04. Never noticed it before: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/901600